# Date from Angular to Laravel is always "now"

Tags: angular, laravel, rest, datetime, datepicker

I'm desperate. I'm trying to send a date to Laravel with Angular and save it in a MySQL database. However, I only get the current date. I will send more information. These arrive correctly. Only at the date he chooses "now". In the database, the date has the type DateTime. The formobject in Angular also has the correct date and is of type Moment.

I have already tried the following. I just passed the date (with _d). Of course I have handed over the complete object. And my current approach is to hand over the day, month and year individually.

I tried it in Laravel with DateTime and now with Carbon unsuccessfully.

Here is my Laravel code

```
public function postLend(Request $request)
    {
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

        'itemid' => 'required|numeric',
        'personid' => 'required|numeric',
        'annotation' => 'required',
        'startdate' => 'required|date',
        'enddate' => 'required|date',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
    }

        $lend = new Lend();
        $lend->itemid = $request->input('itemid');
        $lend->personid = $request->input('personid');
        $lend->annotation = $request->input('annotation');
//        $lend->startdate = $request->input('startdate');
//        $lend->enddate = $request->input('enddate');
        $startDOI = new \DateTime();

$lend->startdate = new Carbon($request->input('startyear'),$request->input('startmonth'),$request->input('startday'));
//var_dump($lend->startdate);
//$startimestamp =  $lend->startdate->getTimestamp();
//var_dump($lend->enddate);


$lend->enddate = new Carbon($request->input('enddate'));

        $lend->save();
        return response()->json(['quote' => $lend], 201);

    }
```

Here is my Angular Code

```
  onChangeData(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.datepicker._selected);
    console.log(form.value.studentid);
    this.lend.itemid = this.items.id;
    this.lend.personid = form.value.studentid;
    // this.lend.personid = form.value.studentid;
    this.lend.annotation = form.value.annotation;
    this.lend.startDate = form.value.startdate._d;

    this.lend.startDay = form.value.startdate._i.date;
    this.lend.startMonth = form.value.startdate._i.month;
    this.lend.startYear = form.value.startdate._i.year;

    this.lend.endDate = form.value.enddate._d;
    console.log(this.lend);

    this.lendService.addLend(this.lend);
  }
```

Laravel get never startdate or enddate.

Comment: First, you should probably add input validation to your controller method. Its built in, might as well use it.

Comment: Very good argument. I get the follow Error: enddate: ["The enddate field is required."] startdate:["The startdate field is required."] . A new approach. A new hope :)

Comment: Yes indeed, now you know its not sending the fields to the back end. Also, you can debug these type of requests with your Chrome dev tools, under the "Network" tab

Comment: It was an typing :(. Thank you so much. The hint helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!